# Google App Script: modify array before setting values in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, adsense-api

I'm using Google's App Script to import AdSense data into a Google Sheet (I'm using [this script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/adsense#generate_a_report) and it's working fine).

Here is sample data I receive (usually the rows number in the hundreds) which is held by the variable `report`:

```
{rows=[
    {cells=[
        {value=2023-08-24}, {value=18628}, {value=32779}, {value=83}, {value=0.31}, {value=0.0045}, {value=1.39}, {value=25.81}
    ]}, 
    {cells=[
        {value=2023-08-25}, {value=11534}, {value=20630}, {value=49}, {value=0.29}, {value=0.0042}, {value=1.25}, {value=14.45}
    ]}
]}
```

And here is the App Script code which appends the data to Google Sheets:

```
sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, 8)
      .setValues(report.rows.map((row) => row.cells.map((cell) => cell.value)));
```

All of this works fine.
My question is: **what is the most computing-efficient way of adding multiple cells (columns) to this data (in between the given cells)?** The content of each cell/column is the same for every row.
If possible, I would like to avoid `for` loops

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `My question is: what is the most computing-efficient way of adding multiple cells (columns) to this data (in between the given cells)?`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You wish to avoid loops and yet your example utilizes a looping method with an inner and outer loop

Comment: You could use [Array.splice() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)